# Generate thumbnails in S3 bucket

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Maybe a stupid question:

I've defined S3 bucket in shopware.yaml file

```
    filesystem:
    public:
        type: 'amazon-s3'
```

But when I run `bin/console media:generate-thumbnails`
I don't see them in the S3 bucket, is it normal? Do I have to upload them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thumbnails are automatically stored in the s3 bucket. They are stored in the same filessystem as the original media files.

Do you see the your original images in that bucket already? If not then the filesystem configuration might not be correct. Refer to the [docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/infrastructure/filesystem#amazon-s3) for help.

If you see your original images in the bucket, the config should be correct. Then please check whether you activated thumbnail generation on the media folders in the shopware administration, by configuring the thumbnail sizes that you need. Refer to the [docs](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/content/media#settings) on how to do this.

If after that the thumbnails still are not generated properly make sure that you have a queue worker running as by default the thumbnails will be created async. You can run `bin/console messenger:consume` to execute the async messages.